# How to draw a rectangle and to highlight an interval inside it using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I would like to draw a rectangle which would represent an interval of values from 1 to n, and I would like to highlight an subinterval inside it. How can I draw a such thing using TikZ? I also would like to indicate the bounds at the right place (*i.e.* proportionally) under the rectangle.

There is an image to illustrate what I want to draw

[image]

Comment: You could connect lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use normal rectangles for this. Note that your start should be `0` rather than `1`. Note also that I used `x=-1cm` to reverse the lengths.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners, x=-1cm, below, minimum height=2em]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\n}{5}
\draw (0,0) node{1} rectangle (\n,1) node at (\n,0) {$n$};
\draw [fill=red] (\n/4,0) node{$n/4$} rectangle (\n/2,1) node at (\n/2,0) {$n/2$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A (slightly) modification of nice (and very concise) *AboAmmar* answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners, minimum height=2em, x=-1cm, below]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\n}{5}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (\n,1);
\draw[fill=red] (0.25*\n,0) rectangle (0.5*\n,1);
\foreach \i/\j in {1/n, 0.5/{n/2}, 0.25/{n/4}, 0/1}
{
\node at (\i*\n,0) {$\j$};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]